# What is the idiom/phrase for doing something to someone and the same thing will also happen to you?

Tags: idiom-requests

I know "karma is a b**ch", "what goes around, comes around", and "you reap what you sow", but I'm looking for a much more elaborate phrase that's very descriptive, which I had heard ages ago but can't recall it anymore.

Comment: What is a b**ch? A bench? A belch? A beach? A brooch? If you want to use a word, use the word. If you don't want to use a word, then just use a different word. You cannot have it both ways. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dF1NUposXVQ

Comment: @RegDwigнt♦ First of all, there's a thing called trying to be decent, and I wasn't sure if the word would violate the rules on here (with or without context). And how would you propose to use a different word in this instance? If you and anybody with knowledge of such a phrase already know what the word is, why does it matter whether it comes with letters or *'s?

Comment: @RegDwigнt♦ cont. "You cannot have it both ways"... based on what authority do you get to make that declaration? How about "I CAN have it both ways"? What's even more amazing is that you, as a moderator, was not only not contributing to the question but elected to criticise people's choice to excercise caution over the use of a potentially sensitive word, when said word was only one of few examples listed to further illustrate the query. It wasn't even the subject matter of the question posed, and you chose to be pedantic over this?!

Comment: Based on the fact that Reg is a moderator.

Comment: @marcellothearcane He can be a moderator or the leader of planet Earth, that has nothing to do with telling people "you cannot have it both ways". The phrase itself is a fallacy. The word in question is integral to the example given, there was no alternative as he erroneously suggested. Just because it was self-censored doesn't preclude its use therein, and it was self-censored because of the exact reason given. If it was indeed okay to use the word then fine. Like I said, I was being cautious, and was ridiculed for it.

Comment: Just dropping this comment here in support of common decency.

Comment: @RegDwigнt There is nothing at all inappropriate about masking out something that could be considered offensive by some, and, therefore, against the site's own rules of conduct. Rather than taking this person to task, you should be appreciating their sense of decorum.

Comment: @Howdy I, for one, applaud your tact in the formation of your question. I believe it was certainly in the spirit of the site.

Comment: @JasonBassford The consensus here is that profanity should not be masked out except in titles, so there was no need to mask it out. Reg could definitely have let Howdy know this in a politer way, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I can't agree with that at all. Unless the subject being masked out is the *specific subject of discussion*, it's perfectly reasonable, if not actually the thing that *should* be done. Are you actually claiming that there's anybody who doesn't know what the intended meaning of the phrase in the question was? (But I do absolutely agree that the way it was handled couldn't have been much politer.)

Comment: @JasonBassford That is not site policy, as far as I know. Obviously, profanity should be used sparingly _by the writer_, but apart from discussing the word itself, site policy is also to let it be when quoting text or phrases, which is exactly what Howdy was doing here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I will continue to disagree. :) If that were an actual quote, there should have at least been attribution, if not a link to the source.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet +1 from myself. I'm just so sick and tired of this let-me-censor-myself-before-anyone-else-does-it nonsense. If I'm gonna censor myself, I'll censor myself properly. By omitting the word altogether. Everything else is just so pathetically half-a****ed.

Answer (score 3):

***What goes around comes around*** idiom

> used to say that if someone treats other people badly he or she will eventually be treated badly by someone else. 
>   (M-W)

Answer (score 1):

> Those who live by the sword die by the sword.

My favourite Source; Matthew 26:52

[BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/matthew/26-52.htm) gives many variants. An example of this version appears in [the Guardian {Simon Weil}](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2002/apr/01/religion.uk).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a much more elaborate phrase that's very descriptive.

I suspect you're looking for this:

> **As you sow so shall you reap.**

From [The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/48500.html):

> Your deeds, good or bad, will repay you in kind...
>
> From the Bible, *Galatians VI* (King James Version):
>
> > Whatsoever a man soweth, that shall he also reap.

Answer (score -1):

Got what I was looking for!

"Turnabout is fair play".

Comment: In my experience, "turnabout is fair play" is most commonly used to mean that it is fair to retaliate against someone for something they did, with an implication that the retaliation will take a similar form to the original offence. That's not really the same as the idea expressed in the question title, that if you do something to someone the same thing *will happen* to you. Retaliation is a choice made by the offended person, not the will of the universe.